# How could i drop rows in Pandas in condition?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, let's take Penguins dataset, and i want to drop all entries in bill_length_mm column when they are more then 30:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

ds = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
ds.head()

ds.drop(ds[ds['bill_length_mm']>30])
```

And it gives me an error. And if i'll try to add axis=1 it'll just drop every column in dataset.

`ds.drop(ds[ds['bill_length_mm']>30], axis=1)`

So what shoud i do to complete ma goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`ds=ds.drop(ds[ds['bill_length_mm']>30].index)`

Or
`ds = ds[ds['bill_length_mm']<=30]`

Answer (score 0):

`ds.drop` is used to drop columns, not rows. If you only want to keep the rows where `bill_length_mm<=30`, you can use

```py
ds = ds[ds['bill_length_mm']<=30]
```